# Building Docker image via Visual Studio fails: "error: Docker is not installed or is not in the current PATH."

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core, dockerfile, visual-studio-2022

I have an Azure Functions project, containing Docker file like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:4-appservice AS base
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 AS runtime
FROM base as debug
COPY --from=runtime /usr/share/dotnet /usr/share/dotnet
RUN ln -s /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/bin/dotnet

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
ARG NUGET_FEED_ACCESSTOKEN
ARG NUGET_FEED_USERNAME
ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS="{\"endpointCredentials\": [{\"endpoint\":\"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/contoso/_packaging/InternalFeed/nuget/v3/index.json\", \"username\":\"${FEED_USERNAME}\", \"password\":\"${FEED_ACCESSTOKEN}\"}]}"
RUN curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/master/helpers/installcredprovider.sh  | sh
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["NuGet.config", "./MyProgram/"]
COPY ["src/Contoso.MyProgram/Contoso.MyProgram.csproj", "MyProgram/src/Contoso.MyProgram/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyProgram/src/Contoso.MyProgram/Contoso.MyProgram.csproj"
# commented-out code bellow fixes the problem
# RUN rm -r "/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets/1.19.6/build/"
COPY . ./MyProgram/
WORKDIR "/src/MyProgram/src/Contoso.MyProgram"
RUN dotnet build "Contoso.MyProgram.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "Contoso.MyProgram.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true
```

When I start Debugging in Visual Studio, everything works fine - container starts, dobugger attached...

When I **"Right click to Dockerfile" -> Build docker image**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuWfR.png)

I got this error

```
/bin/sh: 2: /tmp/MSBuildTemproot/tmpffb29e82951b49b98c8f41a3aef840a4.exec.cmd: docker: not found
5>C:\Users\niel.young\Desktop\casb\repos\MyProgram\src\Contoso.MyProgram\Dockerfile : error CTC1014: #21 6.756 /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets/1.19.6/build/Container.targets(97,5): error : Docker is not installed or is not in the current PATH. [/src/MyProgram/src/Contoso.MyProgram/Contoso.MyProgram.csproj]
```

Can anyone explain me, what is role of microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets inside the container and why does it check, if the Docker is installed inside the container during building process? What is the right approach so I can debug, but also build images without such an error?

I know that I can avoid this error by removing the package from **/root/.nuget/packages** (commented-out line in Dockerfile). But I am not sure if it is the right approach.